Anime movie about a girl having a bad dream involving cake and maybe a parrot?
I am trying to find an anime movie that I briefly watched once. 
Unfortunately I did not watch enough to be able to grab the main plot. I can only remember how it started. 
It is an anime movie that started with a teenage girl that has a bad dream. I can remember that the dream she had, had something to do with a cake and later something evil appeared. 
She was tied to a chair in a very dark room and a cake was in front of her. I think she was forced to eat the cake. I think a parrot was there as well? I cannot remeber exactly what it was.
I think that the evil thing had some kind of tentacles (NO, this is not a hentai movie.) Later the girl wakes up realizing it was only a dream. She realizes she is late for school and quickly gets ready. 
She is asked by her mother if she is going to have breakfast. She only grabs a piece of bread and runs out of the house with the bread in her mouth. She later catches up to her friends that are waiting for her to go to school. 
That is as much as I can remember.
The movie is very colorful and it resembles some of the latest Hayao Miyazaki's movies. I believe the movie is hand-drawn. I can remember that the scenery was very beautiful.You could easily confuse the movie with a Studio Ghibli movie.

Do you know when it's from, or at least when you saw it?

It's not old I guess. Wouldn't be able to tell you when it is from. I watched it around 3 or 4 years ago. From the art style it doesnt look old. Probably from 2000s forwards.
